# How to run maven plugins via go lang

Tags: java, go, maven-plugin

I am currently researching on a way to run maven goals ( in particular the `maven tycho plugin`) on a system without having both `java` and `maven` preinstalled and installing them is not an option. Is there anyway of doing that using `Go lang`?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe using maven docker container is an option in your case - https://hub.docker.com/_/maven/

Comment: AFAIK you need maven and java to run a maven plugin.

Comment: @SzymonStepniak does maven docker needs `java` to be installed priorly

Comment: No, this container is shipped with JDK (you can choose form JDK7 to JDK9). Take a look at paragraph called "Run a single Maven command" on this docker page. It describes how to run single maven goal with this container. Ofc it requires docker daemon to be installed and running.

Answer (score 0):

Java applications require Java, Ruby applications require Ruby, and .NET applications require .NET. You can't run a Java application with Go any more than you can run a Ruby application with gcc or a .NET application with Erlang. These things are not interchangeable.